# Partial View loading using javascript : Possible XSS by FORTIFY

Tags: javascript, fortify

I have a js function , which Fortify identified as XSS vulnerable as below. Can someone suggest any solution for this since the method is intensively used in my web system.

I am here trying to call a partialview in ajax and the result html am appending to a specified dom div

My function look like the below

```
success: function(json) {
    if ((dataType == "json") && (json !== true)) {

    var errorInForm=false;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var value = json[i];

        var errorFieldId = value[0];
        var errorField = $($("#" + errorFieldId)[0]); //this is Fortify error
```

Comment: `$($("#" + errorFieldId)[0])` - this in general creates same element 2 times. Use it just as `$("#" + errorFieldId)`

Comment: Your code appears to be using a library like jQuery, if so we would need more details including that specific version.  Note your code as posted is malformed/incomplete

Comment: Getting the DOM element's ID directly from a request feels a bit odd, have you considered validating that the `errorFieldId` is one of the expected results? (E.g. compare against a list of accepted IDs before directly accessing the DOM, or pass an ID that you use to pick the element from a list rather than the DOM ID itself)

Comment: Sorry i said wrong,this code is from jquery.validationEngine.js but my html did not call any about ajax, also i checked the new version of jquery.validationEngine.js which is the same ajax function